# WP link rewrite

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewriting, wordpress

How I can to remove "category" from this link:
 http://portalchik.factor.ua/category/novosti-i-akcii/

Using ONLY **functions.php**

I hear about `add_rewrite_rule`, but I cannot do it right.

**UPDATE:**

And add to this link
http://portalchik.factor.ua/nalogi-i-buhgalterskiy-uchet-komplekt/
category name!

Answer (score 0):

There is a wordpress plugin that I believe hooks onto the wp-rewrite file and does what you want without modifying the core files. http://wordpress.org/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/